# Can we data inject the array and single data of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dependency-injection

I am actually trying to inject the array and the data inside the array to another component but is constantly getting errors.

My list.component.ts

Here i injected the itemList array from app.component and this component is working just fine. No errors here.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {List} from './list.model'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() itemList: List[] = [];
@Output() onItemSelected: EventEmitter<List>;
private currentItem: List;

constructor(){
  this.onItemSelected = new EventEmitter();
}

onClick(list: List): void {
this.currentItem = list;
this.onItemSelected.emit(list);
console.log(`clicking list title: ${list.title}`);
}

isSelected(list: List): boolean {
 if (!list || !this.currentItem) {
      return false;
    }
    return list.title === this.currentItem.title;
}
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

list.component.html

Here i try to inject both the array and then using `ngFor` i try to inject the single list also.

```
<div class="ui grid posts">
    <app-list-row 
        [lists]="itemList"
        *ngFor="let list of itemList"
        [list]="list"  
        (click)='onClick(list)'
        [class.selected]="isSelected(list)">
    </app-list-row>
</div>
```

list-row.component.ts

I am mainly trying to input the array in this component so that i can use the splice method to delete my list. I tried the `delete list;`method but this says i cannot use delete in strict mode. Therefore i am trying to input the array and use the splice method.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {List} from '.././list/list.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-row',
  inputs: ['list: List'],
  templateUrl: './list-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-row.component.css'],
  host: {'class': 'row'},
})
export class ListRowComponent implements OnInit {
list: List;
@Input() lists: List[];

deletelist(list: List): void {
    let index: number = this.lists.indexOf(list);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.lists.splice(index, 1);
    }
} 
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}

list-row.component.html

In this write a div and use a lable of delete icon and give an event of click with the `"deleteList(list)"`.

```
<div class="Eight wide column left aligned title">
    <div class="value">
        <div class = "hello">
            <b>
            {{ list.title | uppercase }}
            </b>
            <div style="float: right;" class="ui label">
                <i  class="delete icon" 
                (click)="deleteList(list)"
                ></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

These are my codes and i dont know whether i can do the dependency injection of both the array and its single data in the array. If i can, what ways are there to do it. while running in server the console error is

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'list' since it isn't a known property of 'app-list-row'.
1. If 'app-list-row' is an Angular component and it has 'list' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-list-row' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
        [lists]="itemList"
        *ngFor="let list of itemList"
        [ERROR ->][list]="list"  
        (click)='onClick(list)'
        [class.selected]="isSelected(list)">
"): ListComponent@4:2 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'list' since it isn't a known property of 'app-list-row'…, _nativeError: ZoneAwareError, __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'list'…ttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6060:47)", __zone_symbol__message: "Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'list' since …lected]="isSelected(list)">↵"): ListComponent@4:2"} Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'list' since it isn't a known property of 'app-list-row'.
1. If 'app-list-row' is an Angular component and it has 'list' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-list-row' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
        [lists]="itemList"
        *ngFor="let list of itemList"
        [ERROR ->][list]="list"  
        (click)='onClick(list)'
        [class.selected]="isSelected(list)">
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@Input()` to list variable in `ListRowComponent` class and check if it is working or not and remove inputs from metadata.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {List} from '.././list/list.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-row',
  templateUrl: './list-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-row.component.css'],
  host: {'class': 'row'},
})
export class ListRowComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() list: List;
   @Input() lists: List[];

   deletelist(list: List): void {
       let index: number = this.lists.indexOf(list);
       if (index !== -1) {
           this.lists.splice(index, 1);
       }
   } 
   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

or

Remove :List from inputs as

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {List} from '.././list/list.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-row',
  templateUrl: './list-row.component.html',
  inputs :['list']
  styleUrls: ['./list-row.component.css'],
  host: {'class': 'row'},
})
export class ListRowComponent implements OnInit {
   list: List;
   @Input() lists: List[];

   deletelist(list: List): void {
       let index: number = this.lists.indexOf(list);
       if (index !== -1) {
           this.lists.splice(index, 1);
       }
   } 
   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Comment: yes it is giving error..i tried all the different combination here but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I did not do two input bindings but i created a custom event in the list-row.component and emmited the list to list.Component.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {List} from '.././list/list.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-row',
  templateUrl: './list-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-row.component.css'],
  host: {
    'class': 'row'
  }
})
export class ListRowComponent  {
@Input() list: List;
@Output() deleted = new EventEmitter<List>();

deletedl()  {
  const listing: List = this.list;
  this.deleted.emit(listing);
  }
```

In the template I used the click event to call the deletel() method.

```
<div class="Eight wide column left aligned title">
    <div class="value">
        <div class = "hello">
            <b>
            {{ list.title | uppercase }}
            </b>
      <div style="float: right;" class="ui label">
        <i  class="delete icon"
            (click)="deletedl()">
        </i>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I just called the event in the list.component

list.component.html

```
<div class="ui grid posts">
    <app-list-row
        *ngFor="let list of itemList"
        [list]="list"
        (click)='onClick(list)'
        [class.selected]="isSelected(list)"
    (deleted)="deletedl($event)">
    </app-list-row>
</div>
```

Then i called a method in list.component to delete the list from the array using Splice method.

list.component

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {List} from './list.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {
@Input() itemList: List[] = [];
private currentItem: List;

onClick(list: List): void {
this.currentItem = list;
console.log(`clicking list title: ${list.title}`);
}

isSelected(list: List): boolean {
 if (!list || !this.currentItem) {
      return false;
    }
    return list.title === this.currentItem.title;
}
  deletedl(list: List) {
    console.log(`deleting list title: ${list.title}`);
    let index: number = this.itemList.indexOf(list);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.itemList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I have learned that if we want to get some input from the parent component than using property binding helps and when we want to run some output from our parent component then event binding is helpful.